# Unable to Save form Django

Tags: ajax, django

I am trying to save a form to update an existing user, but I am unable to get it to work. The error occurs when I try to save the form. The console shows the error occurs in the view (internal server error).

Form:

```
class updateFirstName(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(updateInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-updateFirst'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = '/login/userInfoChange/'
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

view:

```
@json_view
@csrf_exempt
def userInfoChange(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        user_form = updateFirstName(request.POST)
        print user_form
        if user_form.is_valid():
                user_form.save()

                print "Valid Form"
                return {'success': True}
```

html:

```
<form id="updateUsername">
              <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="submit-username">Change</button>
                  </span>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_firstname" placeholder="First Name: {{user.first_name}}">
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                          $('#submit-username').click(function(){

                                  $.ajax({//begin
                                          type: 'POST', 
                                          url:  '/login/userInfoChange/', 
                                          data: $('#updateUsername').serialize(),    
                                          success: function(result){
                                                  console.log('updateUsername');
                                          }
                                        });

                          });

                   </script>
              </div><br></form>
```

Model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User)
       confirmation_code = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       reset_code = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       address_lineOne = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       address_lineTwo = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       State = models.CharField(max_length=128)
       zipCode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
       def __unicode__(self): 
    return self.user.username
```

---

Solution:

```
first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
user.first_name = first_name
user.save()
```

Thanks ejey for resolving my csrf ajax issue.

Comment: Is that the whole of your view? And what does the error message say if you set DEBUG=True?

Comment: Yes, currently anyway. Im just trying to figure out how to save the form to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intending on posting using ajax you ought to use have a view method such as:

```
def some_ajax_view(request):
    data = request.POST.copy()
        if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
             ...
             ...
```

You can get more information on how to process your ajax request without having to compromise on the csrf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Thank you. I have been meaning to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you didn't answer my question about the error message. This is a *vital* step in debugging, and it's very little use coming onto SO and asking questions without first finding the actual error and doing what you can to fix it yourself.

That said, you do have a huge obvious bug in your code. If the request is not a POST, and/or the form is not valid, what are you expecting to happen? Currently, your code just stops; so in either of those cases it will return `None`, which is an error: all views must return an `HttpResponse`. If you did look at the error message, that is probably what it would say.

You should ensure that your view at least returns an empty HttpResponse in either of those circumstances. More useful, though, would be a response that actually contains the errors from the form validation.

Comment: Firstly, I appreciate your comment. However, if you look at my original post,I gave the error being received, internal server error. I also tell you where the problem was, when it tries to save. I am not concerned with the else clause because the form is obviously valid if the error is occurring in that statement. If I was able to determine the problem other than knowing what line it occurs at I wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: I advise you install django-extensions and use the /.manage.py runserve_shell command. this way you will get more descriptive tracebacks in the terminal.